# Applying pandas operations to all dictionary keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a `pandas` DataFrame `df`:

```
           paper    reference   count
9384155    p25      r50         1
7434371    p98      r9          78
7433400    p7       r27         5
7431765    p101     r91         501
7422256    p22      r5          91
...
```

I created a dictionary that subsets `df` by `count`:

```
df_dict={key:df[df['count']==key] for key in df['count'].unique()}
```

For each sub-DataFrame in `df_dict`, I would like to apply the operations below:

```
df_dict[i] = df_dict[i].drop(['count'], axis=1)

pairs = df_dict[i].merge(df_dict[i], on=["reference"])
pairs = pairs[pairs["paper_x"] < pairs["paper_y"]]
pairs = pairs.groupby(["paper_x", "paper_y"]).count().reset_index()
pairs.columns = ["paper1", "paper2", "common"]

refs = df_dict[i].groupby(["paper"]).count().reset_index()
refs.columns = ["paper", "freq"]

result = pairs.merge(refs, how="left", left_on="paper1", right_on="paper")
result = result.merge(refs, how="left", left_on="paper2", right_on="paper")
result = result[["paper1", "freq_x", "paper2", "freq_y", "common"]]
result.columns = ["paper1", "freq1", "paper2", "freq2", "common"]
```

Note that I created a dictionary so that I can apply the operation to all DataFrames with different `count` value separately.

The `count` column in `df` does not necessarily contain all the integer values, so there may exist `KeyError` that needs to be ignored. I tried running a `for` loop:

```
for i in range(df['count'].max()):
  try:
    c = df_dict[i]
    c = c.drop(['count'], axis=1)
    pairs = c.merge(c,on=['reference'])
    pairs = pairs[pairs["paper_x"] < pairs["paper_y"]]
    pairs = pairs.groupby(["paper_x", "paper_y"]).count().reset_index() 
    pairs.columns = ["paper1", "paper2", "common"]    
    refs = c.groupby(["paper"]).count().reset_index()
    refs.columns = ["paper", "freq"]
    result = pairs.merge(refs, how="left", left_on="paper1", right_on="paper")
    result = result.merge(refs, how="left", left_on="paper2", right_on="paper")
    result = result[["paper1", "freq_x", "paper2", "freq_y", "common"]]
    result.columns = ["paper1", "freq1", "paper2", "freq2", "common"]
  except KeyError:
    continue
```

but the operation returns a single big DataFrame and with incorrect values.

Ideally, I would like a multiple set of `result` DataFrames (separated by `count` like they are in `df_dict`).

Comment: "I tried running a loop for i in range(df['count'].max())..." Please show this as part of your code.

Comment: Sorry, thought it was quite redundant and lengthy. Applied the edit.